# Elisp: Resize displayed images programmatically

Tags: images

I am writing a minor mode which involves fetching some pictures from url and displaying them, but some of them are way too big to fit an emacs window.

**How could I manage to limit the visual size of the displayed picture ?**

For now I am using something like

`(insert-image (create-image pic nil t))`

for display, where pic is a jpeg image raw data as a string.

I spent a lot of time browsing google and couldn't find a tutorial, docs or a code example that would help me rescaling my images.
The [GNU Emacs Lisp reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Images.html#Images) is quite obscure and confusing and doesn't contain much examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fist you should check whether `imagemagick`-support is compiled into emacs.
If `(image-type-available-p 'imagemagick)` returns non-nil you are fine (thanks to [deb0ch](/users/11911/deb0ch) for clarification).

Afterwards you can create images with type `imagemagick` and property `:height` and/or `:width`:
`(create-image "~/test.png" 'imagemagick nil :height 100)`

See [the manual page on ImageMagick images](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/ImageMagick-Images.html).

Comment: Just tested on an emacs compiled without imagemagick and checking for imagemagick support using `(imagemagick-types)` doesn't work: the function is void.
Instead, check for its existence using `(image-type-available-p 'imagemagick)`.

Answer (score 2):

The `:width` and `:height` [keywords](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/ImageMagick-Images.html#ImageMagick-Images) are available to scale the image only for the image type `imagemagick`.

My understanding of the documentation is that rather than using "convenience functions" such as `create-image` and `insert-image` you have to directly build an [image descriptor](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Image-Descriptors.html#Image-Descriptors) and put it as the `display` text property of the position where you want to display the image.

Here's an example (displaying the image `/usr/share/zenity/zenity.png` at position 1 with a width of 100 pixels):

```el
(put-text-property 1 2 'display (cons 'image
 '(:type imagemagick :file  "/usr/share/zenity/zenity.png" :width 100)))
```

Edit: as shown in @Tobias' answer, and contrary to what I say above, you can actually use "convenience functions".

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use [`convert`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) from [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) to [Resize or Scale images](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/).

Alternatively, you can pass `:scale` to `create-image` or use `(setf (image-property my-image :scale) ...)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Though Emacs is built with libmagickWand support, isn't there a way of doing that from inside emacs ? I saw something along those lines [there](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/ImageMagick-Images.html#ImageMagick-Images) with the `:width`, `:max-width`, `:height` and `:max-height` properties, but did not understand how to use it.